# How to get id of new item ngrx

Tags: angular, mongodb, ngrx

I'm using the format of

```
{product._id:{product._id:string, product_name:string}, product._id:{product._id:string, product_name:string}}
```

to hold product info for my store

All works fine, on load I set it up with:

```
function handleBlogsLoadedAction(state, action) {
    const returnedBlogs = action.payload
    const blogObj = returnedBlogs.reduce(
        (blogs: { [id: string]: Blog }, blog: Blog) => 
                 { 
                    return Object.assign(blogs, { [blog._id]: blog }); 
                 }, {});

    let newState = Object.assign({}, state);
     newState = {
        loaded:true,
        blogs:blogObj
    }
    return newState;
}
```

so I end up with something like:

```
{"12345":{product._id:"12345", product_name:"product1"}, "6789":{product._id:"6789", product_name:"product2"}}
```

I have it updating and deleting, however when it comes to adding, the problem is the best way to grab the id after creation so I can insert into state

The thing is I don't want to generate the id myself, the database must do it

Does anyone know best practice or just have some ideas on how to do this

**EDIT:**

My apologies the problem was a little more complicated than is illustrated above.

The answer by @danday74 is the correct answer, but I asked my question poorly and I think I should share and elaborate, as to hopefully help others.

My store also uses websocket to communicate with other clients, the `@Effect() beginUpdate$` listens for the actions:

`BLOG_UPDATE_START_ACTION, BLOG_DELETE_START_ACTION, BLOG_ADD_START_ACTION`

when beginUpdate$ is fired, the next method was called for the socket subject

```
this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify(action))
```

Which carries/sends the action to connected clients, then an action is dispatched from beginUpdate$ to update the database.

You can see the problem developing here, I need to update the database as @danday74 stated *THEN* dispatch the returned data to the store

So what I did, in the end, was take the next method call, which is in a do function, and added it to the effects that make the HTTP calls, so the next method is called with the response from the server

I also have set up an effect listening to the socket:

@Effect() watchSocket$ = this.socketService.socket$

when the action is sent via the socket, it dispatches the actions that update state, but now have the correct payload.

It's been a learning curve implementing websocket into ngrx, for instance, I was originally using the watchSocket$ effect to return an action that would make HTTP calls, then dispatch an action to update state,

but because the action from watchSocket$ is dispatched to all clients, each client would try to make the same HTTP request, imagine having 100 clients trying to remove the same item!

So I separated into 2 effects one to update the database (HTTP requests)

Which sends the response to the socket, which updates all connected stores.

Please if anyone can make any suggestions on best practices, feel free

```
//Effects that make HTTP requests
@Effect({dispatch:false}) updateDB$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
.ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogUpdateDBAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATE_DB_ACTION)
    .mergeMap(action =>  {
        console.log(action)
        return this.blogService.updateBlog(action.payload.blog)
    })
    .do((blog:Blog)=> this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify({type:fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATE_START_ACTION, payload:{blog:blog}})))

    @Effect({dispatch:false}) deleteBlogFromDB$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogDeleteDBAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_DELETE_DB_ACTION)
        .mergeMap(action =>  {     
            console.log(action)
            return this.blogService.deleteBlog(action.payload.blog)
        })
        .do((blog:Blog)=> this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify({type:fromBlogActions.BLOG_DELETE_START_ACTION, payload:{blog:blog}})))

    @Effect({dispatch:false}) addBlogToDB$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogAddToDBAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_ADDED_TO_DB_ACTION)
        .mergeMap(action =>  {     
            console.log(action)
            return this.blogService.addBlog(action.payload.blog)
            .catch(()=>{
                return Observable.of({})
            })
        })
        .do((blog:Blog)=> this.socketService.socket$.next(JSON.stringify({type:fromBlogActions.BLOG_ADD_START_ACTION, payload:{blog:blog}})))

// Effects to update state
    @Effect() deleteBlog$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
        .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogDeletedAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_DELETED_ACTION)
        .map((action)=>new fromBlogUIActions.CrudSucessAction(action))

    @Effect() updateBlog$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
        .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogUpdatedAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATED_ACTION)
        .map((action)=>new fromBlogUIActions.CrudSucessAction(action))


    @Effect() addBlog$: Observable<any> = this.actions$
    .ofType<fromBlogActions.BlogAddedAction>(fromBlogActions.BLOG_ADDED_ACTION)
    .map((action)=>new fromBlogUIActions.CrudSucessAction(action))

// Updates Database (CRUD)
    @Effect() beginUpdate$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATE_START_ACTION, fromBlogActions.BLOG_DELETE_START_ACTION, fromBlogActions.BLOG_ADD_START_ACTION)
    .map((action:any)=>{
           //Update database, but doing it here makes sure it's only done once
        if (action.type === fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATE_START_ACTION) {
           return new fromBlogActions.BlogUpdateDBAction(action.payload);
        }
        if (action.type === fromBlogActions.BLOG_DELETE_START_ACTION) {
            return new fromBlogActions.BlogDeleteDBAction(action.payload);
        }
        if (action.type === fromBlogActions.BLOG_ADD_START_ACTION) {
            return new fromBlogActions.BlogAddToDBAction(action.payload);
        }
    })


// Watches websocket
    @Effect() watchSocket$:Observable<any> = this.socketService.socket$
        .map((action : any) => {
            //Update state across clients
            if (action.type === fromBlogActions.BLOG_UPDATE_START_ACTION) {
                return new fromBlogActions.BlogUpdatedAction(action.payload)
            }
            if (action.type === fromBlogActions.BLOG_DELETE_START_ACTION) {
                return new fromBlogActions.BlogDeletedAction(action.payload)
            }
            if (action.type === fromBlogActions.BLOG_ADD_START_ACTION) {
               return new fromBlogActions.BlogAddedAction(action.payload)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Use ngrx effects with two actions like ADD_PRODUCT and ADD_PRODUCT_SUCCESS, return the inserted object from your server, then add it to store.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have two actions:

ADD_PRODUCT_REQUESTED (with payload)

The payload here is the body for the POST request (see below).
This first action triggers an effect which makes a backend POST (CREATE) request to your server. When the backend request is complete the effect triggers the second action below, passing in the response as the payload.
Optionally, this first action may insert data into the store without the ID so that you can start to display data without waiting for the HTTP request to complete.

ADD_PRODUCT_COMPLETED (with payload)

This receives the payload from the effect and inserts (or updates) the data in the store with the relevant ID.

PS You may also want to consider using ngrx/entity which simplifies working with collections.

You are probably used to actions and reducers. In case, you are not familiar with ngrx/effects here is some sample code which does this kind of thing:

```
@Effect()
allFiltersRequested$ = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType<BimRequestedAction>(BimsActionTypes.BimRequested),
  tap((action) => debug(action)),
  mergeMap((action) =>
    // essential to catchError else an HTTP error response will disable this effect
    this.bimService.getBim(action.payload).pipe(
      catchError(() => {
        return of({})
      })
    )
  ),
  map((bim) => new BimLoadedAction(bim))
)
```

Here the bimService is making the HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for that, it did the trick, I've edited my question, just to make things clearer in what I was trying to do and what I did, thanks again

Comment: np - just an FYI - this approach is taken from the Udemy ngrx ng6 course - just so you know that this is the best approach to the problem

Comment: @danday74 If one was to use entity here, how would they define their selectId implementation since the id is defined on the backend?